# Prevent Child component getting rendered when the state is changed in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent and child component of react. Here i pass the id as a prop from parent to child and i am saving the value of the textarea entered using the state. Whenever i am typing in the textarea. The child component gets updated. how to prevent the child component getting updated on every value entered in the textarea? Please help me.

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    console.log('child component Will '+this.props.id);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('child component Did '+this.props.id);
  }
  render() {
    console.log('child render '+this.props.id);
    return <p>Child {this.props.id}</p>;
  }
}
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      id:1,
      textValue:undefined
    }
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    console.log('parent component Will');
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('parent component Did');
  }
  render() {
    console.log('parent render');
    return <div>
      <textarea onChange={(event)=>{
         this.setState(
           {textValue:(event.target.value)})
        }
          }></textarea>
      <Child id='1'/>
      <Child id='2'/>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

[Code pen Link](https://codepen.io/ashokkumar01cbe/pen/OjveXJ)

Comment: add this function in child component: `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    if(this.props.id == nextProps.id)
      return false;
  }` it will avoid the re-rending when you do setState in parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of extending `React.Component` you can use `React.PureComponent`. The difference between the two is that the latter also performs a **shallow**-comparison of both the `props` and `state` between each render; if nothing has changed, it doesn't update.

This is also recommended on the [**official documentation**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent):

> If your React component's `render()` function renders the same result given the same props and state, you can use `React.PureComponent` for a performance boost in some cases.

---

Have a look at the code below. I have only changed the first line of code to extend the correct class.

```js
class Child extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    console.log('child component Will '+this.props.id);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('child component Did '+this.props.id);
  }
  render() {
    console.log('child render '+this.props.id);
    return <p>Child {this.props.id}</p>;
  }
}
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      id:1,
      textValue:undefined
    }
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    console.log('parent component Will');
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('parent component Did');
  }
  render() {
    console.log('parent render');
    return <div>
      <textarea onChange={(event)=>{
         this.setState(
           {textValue:(event.target.value)})
        }
          }></textarea>
      <Child id='1'/>
      <Child id='2'/>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

*Edit: I updated your question and made your code runnable in a code snippet, so that it can be compared with my snippet.*

Answer (score 2):

You can control when the component should render using [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Your child component would look like this:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    console.log('child component Will '+this.props.id);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('child component Did '+this.props.id);
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if (nextProps.id !== this.props.id) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    console.log('child render '+this.props.id);
    return <p>Child {this.props.id}</p>;
  }
}
```

In this example, the `Child` component will be updated only if its id changes.